# Prestashop 1.7: Display Modules notifications

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to show notifications for my backend module. I can not find documentation for this subject.

I want to show notifications on Modules > Notifications. 
The type of notification I want to show as: 'You need enter your customer name to use this module' or something similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution in the ps_wirepayment module. We need to use:

```
$this->warning = $this->trans('Account owner and account details must be configured before using this module.', array(), 'Modules.Wirepayment.Admin');
```

Example:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = 'ps_wirepayment';

    ...

    parent::__construct();

    ...

    $config = Configuration::getMultiple(array('BANK_WIRE_DETAILS', 'BANK_WIRE_OWNER', 'BANK_WIRE_ADDRESS', 'BANK_WIRE_RESERVATION_DAYS'));

    if (!empty($config['BANK_WIRE_OWNER'])) {
        $this->owner = $config['BANK_WIRE_OWNER'];
    }
    if (!empty($config['BANK_WIRE_DETAILS'])) {
        $this->details = $config['BANK_WIRE_DETAILS'];
    }
    if (!empty($config['BANK_WIRE_ADDRESS'])) {
        $this->address = $config['BANK_WIRE_ADDRESS'];
    }
    if (!empty($config['BANK_WIRE_RESERVATION_DAYS'])) {
        $this->reservation_days = $config['BANK_WIRE_RESERVATION_DAYS'];
    }


    if (!isset($this->owner) || !isset($this->details) || !isset($this->address)) {
        $this->warning = $this->trans('Account owner and account details must be configured before using this module.', array(), 'Modules.Wirepayment.Admin');
    }
    if (!count(Currency::checkPaymentCurrencies($this->id))) {
        $this->warning = $this->trans('No currency has been set for this module.', array(), 'Modules.Wirepayment.Admin');
    }
}
```